# Subclipse commit fails (Eclipse)

Tags: svn, subclipse

I have Subclipse plugin installed.

When I have following setting: `Team -> SVN -> SVN interface Client =` **SVNKit (Pure Java) SVNKit v1.7.9.9659** I get error for committing (formatting is preserved):

> add -N path_to_my_project
>
> svn: E155021: The path 'path_to_my_project' appears to be part of a
>   Subversion 1.7 or greater
>
> working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
>
> working copy.

When I have `Team -> SVN -> SVN interface Client =` **JavaHL (JNI) 1.7.10 (r1485443)** I get similar error for committing:

> add -N path_to_my_project
>
> The working copy needs to be upgraded
>
> svn: Working copy 'path_to_my_project' is too old (format 10, created
>   by Subversion 1.6)

How to solve this (how to upgrade my client or upgrade working copy)?

*P.S.* Each time after changing SVN interface Client I restart Eclipse.

`Help -> Check for Updates` returns `No updates were found`.

Installed Eclipse Features:

- Subversive Client Adapter 1.8.6
- Subversion JavaHL 1.7.10
- Subversion Revision Graph 1.1.1
- SVN Team Provider Core 1.8.22
- SVNKit Client Adapter 1.7.9.2

Installed software:

- JNA Library 3.4.0.t20120117_1605
- Subclipse (Required) 1.8.22
- Subversion Client Adapter (Required) 1.8.6
- Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter 1.7.10
- Subversion Revision Graph    1.1.1
- SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required) 1.7.9.2
- SVNKit Library   1.7.9.r9659_v20130411_2103

**Solved:**

It was my fault, I copied folder from one project *(that had hidden .svn folder inside)* to my current project. So, there is why my project behaved as it was part of Subversion 1.6 and 1.7 at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`svn upgrade`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.upgrade.html) or corresponding command in SVNKit.

You can also checkout a fresh working copy.

Comment: how to do this in eclipse?

Comment: I installed SVNKit using `Help -> Install new software` with http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x url.

Comment: `svn upgrade` refers to upgrading your Working Copy to newer format. You can also checkout a fresh working copy and it will work.

Comment: I tried `Project -> Team -> Upgrade`, but other error occurs: `svn: E155019: Can't upgrade 'path_to_project' as it is not a pre-1.7 working copy directory`. It is strange.. Fresh checkout also didn't help.

Comment: I found out very strange behaviour: committing new file is successful, committing new folder is successfull, but committing new file inside folder give a mistake! wtf

Comment: solved. bahrep - thank you for your efforts. sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @akapelko what was the cause?

Comment: I wrote solution at the end of my question